# Operation on Array Address

Tags: c, arrays

I do not know whether my question is appropriate or not.
If there is a code....

```
int a[2];
```

If I want to check `&a[0]%8==1` and do the operation  `a[0]= (a[0] & ~7)`, is this valid way of doing?

Comment: And what are you trying to do?

Comment: to see weather address is mod by 8.....if not make it to start with mod 8

Comment: You are checking the address, but adjusting the contents.

Comment: You can't just make an address start aligned by 8 by assigning to it...

Answer (score 3):

It is not you who gets to decide the address of an array, it's the compiler+linker to decide at compile+load-time. (And you cannot assign to arrays, only to elements of arrays.)

If you need suitably aligned memory, use the `malloc()` function from `<stdlib.h>`. The C language standard guarantees that the pointer returned by `malloc` is suitably aligned for any type. If the minimum requirements for any type is 8, this will be an 8-byte aligned pointer. So what you should do is:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main (void)
  {
      int *a;

      a = malloc (2 * sizeof(*a));
      if (a == NULL) { /* Handle out of memory. */ }
      /* ... */
  }
```

This is actually a bit of overkill, since an array-of-int declared with `int a[2];` will very likely have an alignment supporting fastest operation. Why is it you think forcing 8-byte alignment would be advantageous?